# Media queries not working on iPhone's Mail

Tags: iphone, css, email, media-queries, newsletter

I'm facing a problem with a newsletter. I have included media queries in it so mobile viewers get something nicer. If I view my newsletter in a browser and resize it, I can see that it works fine, both on mobile/desktop. But when I view it through iphone's Mail app, my media queries are getting ignored for some reasons I'm not aware about. The mailbox I'm testing it with isn't a gmail one by the way.

You can see it here : http://www.libraryofarts.com/newsletters/11-06-13/

Here's the head part of my code :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Pre-Opening librairie LO/A</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        #outlook a{padding:0;}
        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;}
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
        img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}

        /* 
        *   RESET STYLES 
        */

        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
        img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
        body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

        /* 
        *   MOBILE STYLES 
        */

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){

            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

            #bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}

            /* ======== Page Styles ======== */

            #templateContainer{
                max-width:700px !important;
                 width:100% !important;
            }

            h1{
                 font-size:24px !important;
                 line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h2{
                 font-size:20px !important;
                 line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h3{
                 font-size:18px !important;
                 line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h4{
                 font-size:16px !important;
                 line-height:100% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Header Styles ======== */

            #templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */

            #templateHeader p {
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            #templateHeader p > a {
                text-decoration:none; color:inherit;
            }

            #headerImage{
                height:auto !important;
                 max-width:700px !important;
                 width:100% !important;
            }

            .headerContent{
                 font-size:20px !important;
                 line-height:125% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Body Styles ======== */

            .bodyContent{
                 font-size:18px !important;
                 line-height:125% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Column Styles ======== */

            .templateColumnContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}

            .columnImage{
                height:auto !important;
                 max-width:480px !important;
                 width:100% !important;
            }

            .leftColumnContent{
                 font-size:16px !important;
                 line-height:125% !important;
            }

            .rightColumnContent{
                 font-size:16px !important;
                 line-height:125% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Footer Styles ======== */

            .footerContent{
                 font-size:14px !important;
                 line-height:115% !important;
            }

            .footerContent.Bottom {
                text-align : center;
            }

            .footerContent.Bottom .online {
                margin-left : 0;
                margin-top : 10px;
                display : block;
            }

            .footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */

            .footerContent ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin : 0;
                padding : 0;
            }

            .footerContent ul li {
                float : none !important;
            }

            .footerContent ul li img {
                display : block;
                margin : 0 auto;
            }

            .test {display : none !important;}
        }
    </style>
```

Has anyone an idea on why I can't get this media query working through iphone's Mail ?

Thanks,

Comment: can i ask why almost everything has !important, you do not need this, as long as your css for media queries is at the bottom of all other stylesheets then it will be the last thing to be read and will be rendered correctly.. using !important is such a bad practice and only to be used in exceptional circumstances IMHO

Comment: I'm using inline styling, except for the media queries block which resides in the <head>

Comment: Dude seriously stop it, setup some CSS style sheets and do it properly

Comment: @Richlewis Did you get that my goal is to send a newsletter ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how small you think the project is, do it properly, dont get into bad habits

Comment: @Richlewis I wasn't thinking about the project being small or not. It's just that you can't use external stylesheets when it comes to create newsletters.

Comment: hmm didnt know that, so i will apologise for being too harsh, however not all selectors are ignored so you could tidy things up a bit by not having everything inline see this http://www.xequte.com/support/maillistking/css_in_emails.html..but back to your problem, when you say it doesnt work, what specifically isnt working? can you provide an example of newsletter being rendered?

Comment: @Richlewis No matter! Well actually I found that media queries are working (I've attributed a test class on a paragraph and set it to display none, and it worked within the email). My problem is that this part of the media query is not doing anything :

.templateColumnContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}


It's the most important thing that will break my columns into one single. Works fine in the browser, but on the iphone, I'm still having 2 columns.

Comment: try taking the width 50% out of the inline style for that class.. may have some conflicts there

Comment: @Richlewis Thing is that if I remove the inline style, then it will be ugly in gmail, as it strips everything in the <head>

Comment: ok this is a bit dirty i guess but what about adding another media query including orientation : portrait and landscape and placing the class in there?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue

You should use " visibility : hidden " rather than " display : none " (property). I faced the same problem and resolved it with the help of "visibility"

```
element {
  visibility: visible;
}

element {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

other example :

```
{ visibility: hidden; }   
{ visibility: visible; }  
{ visibility: collapse; }
```

You don't need " !important " at all if you use the correct CSS Property

Read this for more clarity :

[w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

[difference between display and visibility](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-css-display-and-visibility#:%7E:text=CSS%20Display%20%E2%88%92%20none%20does%20not,made%20visible%20to%20the%20user.)