# Media queries on iphone mail

Tags: html, iphone, css, media-queries, newsletter

I am trying to use media queries for iphone newsletters but I didn't even manage to make a very basic example work. Can someone help me out understanding why the color of the span in the following example is still blue even on iPhone? I tried to remove the meta tag viewport, I even removed the inline style on the span, but still the span never turns green.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style type="text/css">

.test{
    color: #FF0000;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    .test{
        color: #00FF00 !important;
    }
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="w600 l-content-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
            <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="w600" height="55" width="600" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
                        <span class='test' style='color: #0000FF'>Test</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see there is a [very similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066613/media-queries-not-working-on-iphones-mail) to this one but it got no answer and my problem is a little bit more basic.

I test this sending as email the HTML opened in IE8

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is quite a lot of documentation available via Apple's developer portal (no need to register). For your specific question this ressource should do the trick:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html

This is also a good entry point to learn more about web apps on iOS ranging from technical stuff to the user interface guidelines

---

That being said, you should just reorder your CSS so that the @media query is the final part of the CSS (since it needs to overwrite previous CSS definitions, which it can't if they are ordered your way).

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I have to reorder the CSS. Still it doesn't work. The text is still blue. I also check the precious link you sent me but didn't find anything specifically related to this issue. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Try using this media query: `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {...}`